# function not defined (script not being called?)

Tags: javascript, magento

```js
function myClick(){
    console.log("aa");
    window.location.reload();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" click="selectAddress" class="action action-select-shipping-item" onclick="myClick()">
    <span translate="'Ship Here'"></span>
</button>
```

Im trying to call a function when i click a button but im always getting this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: myClick is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

I tried changing the script position but its alwways the same , also i tried using addeventlistener and stills the same.

I know i can put window.local.reload right in the onClick but im using this just for testing because i want to put another function inside but first i need that the button onclick works properly.

PS: im using Magento 2.3.5 and editing the default.html inside the Magento_Checkout module in adress renderer .im trying to update de checkout summary when i click the Ship Here button when changing adress so that way it will update the tax.

Comment: Works fine with the code you provided.

Comment: It works for me. Just make sure that the button is only clickable once the script containing your function has loaded.

Comment: @AlphaHowl: Should be a given since it is an inline click event.

Comment: @Lain yes but maybe the OP included the script like this just to make it look simpler for SO purposes.